# How to add variables to JMeter script programmatically

Tags: java, jmeter

I am in process of migrating Postman collections to jMeter. I have no problem importing Postman  collection itself, but the variables are the problem. My Postman collections rely on them heavily. I can export the variables from Postman, but couldn't find the way to import them. I also need to apply some logic while importing. I am thinking about writing the Java code to import the Postman variables into jMeter. The jMeter class which seems to hold the variables is ValueReplacer and I know how to add variables to ValueReplacer, but couldn't find the way to add the populated ValueReplacer to test plan and save it.

My code which loads the test plan:

```
    StandardJMeterEngine standardJMeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jMeterHome + "/bin/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jMeterHome);
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();
    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File(jMeterScript));
    standardJMeterEngine.configure(testPlanTree);
    ValueReplacer valueReplacer = geterateValueReplacer(new File(postmanExportedVariables));
    // add valueReplacer to testPlanTree  and save
```

So I am able to load the script and generate the ValueReplacer. Is there a way to add valueReplacer object to the script and save it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly call the ValueReplacer class, if you want to run an existing JMeter test plan from Java code just make sure that JMeter Variables are just declared in their respective places via [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) or come from the [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

So if you declare the variable `foo` with the value of `bar` in the User Defined Variables:

[image]

You will be able to refer it as `${foo}` where required:

[image]

If you run your JMeter test from Java code JMeter will evaluate the variable in the runtime and resolve their values.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation it doesn't seem to be possible to import Postman variables directly. Since none of the Postman to jMeter converters I found can handle everything I need: Postman variables, formdata, oauth2 I ended up writing my own converter